# class constructor problem. cant get what I want to show in my div

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

Sorry , this might be a stupid question but I dont really get why this won't work for me. I just want to be able to write the result from myitem in to a simple div. I have used a function onmouseover to get it to work. but that can't be neccessary. And i know how to show it in an alert.

But how do one get myitem to show in a div?

help is much appreciated!:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> class </title>

    <script>
        class item {
            constructor(name, price, quantity) {

                
                this.name = name;
                this.price = price;
                this.quantity = quantity;

            }
            
            sum() {
                return this.price * this.quantity;
            }
        }
        myitem = new item("apple", 10, 2);


        // This doesnt work //   document.getElementById("example1").innerHTML = myitem.sum();  
        // This doesnt work //        document.getElementById("example1").innerHTML = (myitem.sum());   

        
        //this down below works
         function myfunction () {
             
             document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML = myitem.sum();
         }

            // This works //     alert(myitem.sum());
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="example1"> example1 </div>
    <br/>
      <div id="example2" onmouseover="myfunction();"> example2 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<div id="example1"> example1 </div>` isn't rendered by the time your script is running, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: oh, so just because I had script before the "body" it was not runned as I wanted it to be ? thanks. I got it working for me now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling the function until the event happens, and the comments where it doesn't work is because you are running the script before the `DOM` is loaded. You can use the window event `DOMContentLoaded`which fires once the `DOM` is loaded or you can move your script to below your `Html` body, if you go with the window event `DOMContentLoaded` you can do something like the following:

```
class item {
        constructor(name, price, quantity) {
            
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.quantity = quantity;

        }
        
        sum() {
            return this.price * this.quantity;
        }
    }
    myitem = new item("apple", 10, 2);


    //this down below works
     function myfunction () {             
         document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML = myitem.sum();
     }

     //wait for the DOM to load and then call the function
     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
         myfunction();
     });
```